# is there a way to map a complex query result of sqflite in flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, join, dart, orm

The situation is as follows: I have a query

```
SELECT
    n.id_nota, n.titulo, n.contenido, n.fecha_creacion, n.fecha_modificacion,
    gn.id_grupo_nota, gn.titulo AS titulo_gn, gn.descripcion,
    dn.id_documento_nota, dn.id_nota AS id_nota_dn, dn.id_tipo_documento_nota AS    id_tipo_documento_nota_dn, dn.contenido AS contenido_dn ,
    tdn.id_tipo_documento_nota, tdn.nombre
FROM nota n
LEFT JOIN grupo_nota gn ON n.id_grupo_nota = gn.id_grupo_nota
LEFT JOIN documento_nota dn ON n.id_nota = dn.id_nota
LEFT JOIN tipo_documento_nota tdn ON tdn.id_tipo_documento_nota = dn.id_tipo_documento_nota
WHERE
    n.id_usuario = 1
ORDER BY
    n.fecha_modificacion ASC
LIMIT 5
```

which returns the following Map

```
[
    {
        id_nota: 1, 
        titulo: "Game Cube 5x5", 
        contenido: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...", 
        fecha_creacion: 2020-05-04T04:53:36.360993, 
        fecha_modificacion: 2020-05-04T04:53:36.361028, 
        id_documento_nota: 2, 
        id_nota_dn: 1, 
        id_tipo_documento_nota_dn: 1, 
        contenido_dn: "dart.png"
    }, 
    {
        id_nota: 1, 
        titulo: Game Cube 5x5, 
        contenido: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..., 
        fecha_creacion: 2020-05-04T04:53:36.360993, 
        fecha_modificacion: 2020-05-04T04:53:36.361028, 
        id_documento_nota: 1, 
        id_nota_dn: 1, 
        id_tipo_documento_nota_dn: 1, 
        contenido_dn: "flutter-icon.png"
    }
]
```

Which is fine, but I don't know how to map it so that it returns the following:

```
[
    {
        id_nota: 1, 
        titulo: "Game Cube 5x5", 
        contenido: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...", 
        fecha_creacion: 2020-05-04T04:53:36.360993, 
        fecha_modificacion: 2020-05-04T04:53:36.361028, 
        ls_documento_nota: [
            {
                id_documento_nota: 2, 
                id_nota_dn: 1, 
                id_tipo_documento_nota_dn: 1, 
                contenido_dn: "dart.png", 
            },
            {
                id_documento_nota: 1, 
                id_nota_dn: 1, 
                id_tipo_documento_nota_dn: 1, 
                contenido_dn: "flutter-icon.png", 
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I come from the Spring ecosystem where his ORM made it automatic (as if by magic). I need help with this pls.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it, but I'm fairly certain that [moor](https://moor.simonbinder.eu/) contains this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Result Map in sqflite cannot contains subcollection so you will always get the row result as you get now. SQLite itself only return list or rows where each row contains a list of simple values. You will either need another solution on top of it or...simply manipulate the result (pure dart) to get to the format you want using some king of map converter.